# The number of lattice points in d-dimensional ball

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, integer-lattices, analytic-combinatorics, geometry-of-numbers

The following [paper](http://dmle.cindoc.csic.es/pdf/MATEMATICAIBEROAMERICANA_1995_11_02_08.pdf) states that the number of lattice points in a $d$-dimensional ball of radius $R$ is $V_d R^d + O(R^\alpha)$ where $\alpha = d - 2$ and $V_d$ is the volume of the unit $d$-dimensional ball.

The paper cites a German book *Einführung in die Gitterpunktlehre* by F. Fricker for the proof. A similar statement also appears in this [paper](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa85/aa8536.pdf), again without proof (or citation).

References to the proof of the above statement will be very helpful.

Comment: I think you need $d\ge 4$.  The statement is definitely false for $d=1$ and $d=2$.

Comment: You're probably right. I'm only interested in cases where $d$ is large enough.

Comment: While quite late to the question, [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/310936/is-there-a-relation-between-the-number-of-lattice-points-lie-within-these-circle) seems quite relevant.

Comment: 6 years late. I don't know about this $\alpha=d-2$. If other people are interested and can settle for $\alpha=d-1$, then a complete proof appears in Reed-Simon Volume 4, proof of Proposition 2, page 267 (it's related to eigenvalue problems).

Comment: For the people who are not able to open the first paper link (seems it's not working now) an alternate link is here: http://dmle.icmat.es/pdf/MATEMATICAIBEROAMERICANA_1995_11_02_08.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The second linked paper has several citations. See also the intro in this paper: [Fernando Chamizo and Carlos Pastor: Lattice points in bodies of revolution II](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.08593).